# How-to do regex in macros?

Tags: crystal-lang

```
{% nilable = /\:\:Nil|\?$/.match(type) %}
```

It doesn't seem to work: `undefined macro method 'RegexLiteral#match'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Macros::StringLiteral` has `=~` instance:

```
{% type = "Module::Nil" %}
{% p type =~ /\:\:Nil|\?$/ %} #=> true

{% type = "Module::Null" %}
{% p type =~ /\:\:Nil|\?$/ %} #=> false
```